# Is there a way to know if a dijit.Tree node is open or closed?

Tags: tree, dojo

`isExpandable` tells you if a `dijit.Tree` has children, but what tells you if this tree is open (expanded) or closed?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a reference to the tree node, you can simply ask

```
if(node.isExpanded == true) 
{   
   //your code here 
}
```